# Chrome keeps installing a second copy of itself

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-8.1, installation

I'm running Windows 8.1 and Chrome v40.0.2214.94 m. For some reason, every other day Chrome installs a second copy of itself. My profile and everything stay the same, no problems there, but if I completely close Chrome and reopen it (or next time I boot the computer and open Chrome then) I get a message stating that an administrator has installed a system-level installation of Chrome that will now replace mine. I can uninstall the extra copy (it always has the day's install date listed in Programs and Features, so I know which one to uninstall), and I have no problems using Chrome afterward.

None of my data are being deleted or overwritten or anything, so this isn't really high priority, but something is clearly wrong since Chrome shouldn't be installing an extra copy of itself. Any ideas as to how I can prevent it from doing so in the future?

Comment: Have you run an anti-virus? Often unusual events are caused by viruses. Viri is not the plural. :)

Comment: My recent installation along with a reinstall of Windows went to the Program Files(x86) directory, so does Chrome still install within your user account if you're running as an administrator? I didn't see anything about changes to how Chrome installs when used with an administrator account, but it's possible that Google got tired of it being per-user and wants it available to all users on a PC even if the alternate installer wasn't used. If so, that may now be getting rolled out to the old-style installs.

Comment: I did do full virus and malware scans, nothing was returned. @fencepost, that's an interesting idea. I reinstalled Windows/Chrome on January 2, but the problem is still happening. I'll try backing up my info, uninstalling both Chrome installations, then reinstalling fresh using the latest installer from Google. I'll let you know how that goes.